# Python Array Item Remove

Tags: python, arrays

I have some Python experience, but (obviously) not an overwhelming wealth of knowledge. In short, I need to create validation arrays for Neural Network testing using 1/5th of a main array. So, I am able to append i % 5 == 0 values to a test array. From there, I can still print every 5th value. Now, when I go to remove values, I get the out of index or range error; I know it is because the remove is changing the overall value of len(string_arr). However, I have been unsuccessful in figuring out a way to compensate.

Below is a 'dummy' program to solve what I need, but not the actual thing I am working on. I need 1/5th on a validation array, remove that 1/5th from the main array, and have 4/5th left on the main to train on. Below, I tried to appended to another array and remove those values in order to not mess up the len(string_arr)... did not work.

Thank you

```
english_list = open('file')
for word in english_list.readlines():
word = word[:-1].lower()
if len(word) == 6:
    string_arr.append(word)
    target_arr.append(0)
print(string_arr)
print(len(string_arr))


for i in range(len(string_arr)):
    if i % 5 == 0:
        test_arr.append(string_arr[i])

for i in range(len(string_arr)):
    if i % 5 == 0:
        one_more.append(string_arr[i])

for i in range(len(string_arr)):
    if one_more[i] == string_arr:
        string_arr.remove(one_more[i])

print(test_arr)
print(len(test_arr))
print(string_arr)
print(len(string_arr))
```

Comment: Can you use external libraries? If so check this [method](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) from sklearn

Comment: Perhaps you would like to correct the indentation of your code so it is runnable and makes sense.

Comment: @JosepJoestar thank you and I am aware of some of the simplicity the sklearn adds to all this, but I must create the separate arrays

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a slightly more compact manner with fancy list indexing:

```
small_cut = string_arr[::5]
remaining = [j for sub in zip(string_arr[1::5], string_arr[2::5], string_arr[3::5], string_arr[4::5]) for j in sub]
```

This is assuming you're working with normal python lists; if you're working with something like a numPy array, there might be even easier approaches (potentially more efficient, too) to do what you want.

Comment: NameError: name 'j' is not defined

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers did you get the whole line?

Comment: err... copy-paste issue indeed, my bad xD